# Angular - Http with API returning number larger than 16 digits

Tags: python, angular

As you can see in the question, I try to fetch an API I made with Python that return ID as a number (very important !). But the tool I use is generating ID as number and with more than 16 digits.

So when I fetch my API, all ID is wrong because it exceeds 16 digits.

I have already tried to cast in BigInt for example. But it doesn't work because the cast seems to be applied just after the HTTP result (in chrome's network section I can see the right ID)

Have you any idea of how to deal with more than 16 digits? Or I should consider moving to another tool?

I'm using PysonDB in python to store in json my data.

Thank you for any answer :)

Comment: Just return it as a string?

Comment: Thanks :) In the API ? Before I wanted to have the possibility to not modify the way the api works to learn a little more about javascript limit but I definitely can cast number in string when I return it in the API (well I will have to do the trick for every request :/)